# Parametric NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, parametric-functions

I have to solve a differential system for different parameters and variable initial conditions. I have for example a system like this

```
Do[ss[a][b]=ParametricNDSolve[{EQϕ2, EQr2, EQθ2, r[0] == r0, r'[0] == v0,ϕ[0] ==f0, ϕ'[0] == -0.1 r'[0], θ[0] ==Pi/2, θ'[0] == 0.1 ϕ'[0]}, {ϕ,r, θ}, {τ, 0, 5000}, {r0, f0, v0}, Method -> {StiffnessSwitching, Method -> {ExplicitRungeKutta, Automatic}}, AccuracyGoal -> 15,PrecisionGoal -> 16,  MaxSteps -> Infinity], {a, arange}, {b, brange}]
```

where the initial conditions and a and b vary in a given range:

```
initcond = Table[{r0, f0, v0}, {r0, 1880, 1920}, {f0, 0.85, 1.15, 0.05}, {v0,0.0030, 0.0050, 0.0001}]~Flatten~2;
arange=Range[0.1,0.5,0.1]
brange=Range[5000,10000]
```

Now, after evaluating this Do cycle, I would like to do different operations on the solutions, but I don't know how to handle the syntax for the initial conditions! First, I find x[a][b] and y[a][b] for every set of parameters:

```
Do[x[a][b]][tt_] =rr[a][b][tt] Sin[θθ[a][b][tt]] Cos[ϕϕ[a][b][tt]] /.ss[[a][b]][[1]] /.tt -> τ, {a, arange}, {b,brange}];
Do[y[a][b][tt_] = rr[a][b][tt] Sin[θθ[a][b][tt]] Sin[ ϕϕ[a][b][tt]] /.ss[[a][b][[1]] /.tt -> τ, {a,arange}, {b, brange}];
```

Now I'm not able to make further operations keeping in mind the variable init.conditions. For example, If I find the quantity

```
Do[s[a][b]=(x[a][b][τ=10]-6)^2,{a,arange},{b,frange}]
```

how could I know for which set of initial conditions I find the minimum s[a][b]?